# Is it acceptable to open and then close the session for an external module?

Tags: php, session, authentication, module, destroy

I'm writing a small reusable user manager for my projects that will use services as facebook, persona.org for login. From the point of view of each web, it's an include and a couple of echoes. However, it uses **$_SESSION**, so I need it initialized. For that I use this code in 'include.php':

```
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
  if (headers_sent()) {
    throw new Exception ("You must include this file before sending any header.");
    }
  session_start();
  $NoSession = 1; // Leave everything as it was before
  }

// MAIN CODE HERE

if ($NoSession) {
  session_destroy();
  }
```

**Is it a good idea to destroy the session with [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) or is it acceptable to leave the session opened for this situation?** My point at destroying it is leaving the variables environment as it was before of including the code, making the smallest possible footprint.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly acceptable to leave it open - it's has a negligible footprint. [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) doesn't actually close the session - you need to do a bit more (see the example in the docs).

It's also worth saying you need to call [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to use `$_SESSION` variables, even if a session is left over from the last page visit.

Comment: To allow for seamless integration. If they/me had already `session_start();` somewhere, there's no need to change any code to include the UserManager.